# Merge two arrays based on first element

Tags: scala

I have 2 arrays `Array[(Int, Int)]`, and `Array[(Int, List[String])]`, 
for examples:

```
    (1, 2) and (1, (123, 456, 789)) 
    (2, 8) and (2, (678, 1000))
    (3, 4) and (3, (587, 923, 168, 392))
```

I would like to merge these two arrays into one `Array [(Int, List[String], Int)]` like this:

```
    (1, (123, 456, 789), 2)
    (2, (678, 1000), 8)
    (3, (587, 923, 168, 392), 4)
```

and would like scala still realize the second element is a `List[String]`, 
I tried many ways they can combine these 2 maps or arrays, but cannot realize the second element is a `List[String]`, after merging, it treated the second element as `Any` or `Some` and cannot traverse it.

Comment: Do you want to merge with a `join` or with a `zip`? Seems like it could go either way with your example. What have you tried so far?

Comment: To get more helpful replies, I suggest that you include your attempts (namely **code samples**) at solving it.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution:

```
array1.zip(array2).map { 
     case ((p1,count), (p2,categoryList)) => (p1,categoryList,count) 
}
```